# Convert hdbtable to SQL

Tags: sql, hana

Is there common approach to translate `.hdbtable` file to pure `SQL create table` statement?

Comment: Throwing out a suggestion here, but could you log all the SQL statements to capture the specific CREATE TABLE syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You mean translate a HDB Table to pure SQL statement? If this, you can open the table,and click 'Export SQL' button.

Comment: No, I exactly mean translation of `.hdbtable` to the SQL statement. One of the options is to import table from `.hdbtable` file (is it possible?) and then export as you described above.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't import `.hdbtable` file to HDB ever, but I did import `.csv` file to HDB as a table.

Comment: As far as I know it's possible to extract whole table with values into the either binary file or `.csv` file. And then you could import this units, but I don't know anything about importing `.hdbtable`s. I believe that it's possible, this fact that HANA automatically does it on build and unable to do it in runtime sounds silly.

Answer (score 0):

As hdbtable uses the same type names as the the CREATE/ALTER TABLE statements you could write an hdbtable->sql-ddl compiler that could run completely without HANA. Just keep in mind that the identifiers in hdbtable definitions will be rendered as quoted identifiers if the hdbtable runtime inside HANA computes the definitions.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it wouldn't be a common approach :)